# Writing from 2 separate Spark processes into 1 HDFS directory

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I was wondering whether I can write from 2 separate Spark processes into 1 HDFS directory. Will there be a file names collision in this case. Files are written in form of 'part-00000-00c0472e-a01e-4ea6-b247-57114107c762.c000.txt'. Is there a chance that 2 separate Spark processes generate identical file names and one overwrites files of the other?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964736/multiple-spark-jobs-appending-parquet-data-to-same-base-path-with-partitioning  Looks like aspects tk consider.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks for pointing this out